# Writing to partitioned table in bigquery from Dataflow python job

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When I write to a partitioned table in bigquery from dataflow, I'm getting the following error - could any one help me with this?

> Invalid table ID \"test$20181126\". Table IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores) and must be at most 1024 characters long. Also, Table decorators cannot be used.

This is the python snippet I'm using for writing

```
import apache_beam as beam


class bqwriter(beam.PTransform):
    def __init__(self, table, schema):
        super(BQWriter, self).__init__()
        self.table = table
        self.schema = schema

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        pcoll | beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(
            self.table,
            schema=self.schema,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
        ))
```

Im creating tabe like below

```
a | 'BQWrite' >> BQWriter("test-123:test.test$20181126", table_schema)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My solution was to :

- Either add a date column to the data, then set the BQ table to be partitioned on it
- Or set the default partitioning on _PARTITIONTIME in BQ.

Both these options mean you only insert into test-123:test.test

As to whether we should be able to do what you were trying to do, it seems yes. The [Beam JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2122) states they fixed it for Java, but I couldn't find a status for python.

Comment: Then how I can make it daily truncate and load

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. Have you tested to just write to your table and assume BQ will do the work thanks to the _PARTITIONTIME / the custom partitioning column ? Depending on your use case, you might be better off scheduling a load job / a query

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to pass a function to the native `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery` class :

```
def table_fn(element):
    current_date = date.fromtimestamp(element['timestamp']).strftime("%Y%m%d")
    return f"{bq_output_table}${current_date}"

user_parent_user_watchever_pcol | "Write to BigQuery" >> 
beam.io.Write(
    beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
        table_fn,
        schema=schemas.VIDEOCATALOG_SCHEMA,
        method="STREAMING_INSERTS",
        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
    )
)
```